# IE7 overflow:auto bug

Tags: internet-explorer-7, overflow

Does anybody knows where is the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/jDNFU/ in IE7? I've already tryed everything I could do.

Comment: Mention what have you tried .

Comment: I've tried to enable hasLayout for <li> and for <input>, changing min-height. But the problem actually not only in overflow, but in position relative + overflow

Comment: I meant that you should mention what you have tried to solve your problem **in the question itself** , so that others can know about it and try to help accordingly.

Comment: I also tried to use CSS hack for max-height (expression), but the problem is not in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use something like this? What are you trying to do? What does it need to look like?

```
<ul id="mytest">
    <li><input type="text" value="" name="test1" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="" name="test2" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="" name="test3" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="" name="test4" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="" name="test5" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="" name="test6" /></li>
</ul>

#mytest {list-style:none; width:254px; max-height:328px; overflow-y:auto; display:block;}
#mytest li {position:relative; display:inline; zoom:1; height:25px;}
#mytest input {position:absolute;}
```

**EDIT:**
Since you fixed it yourself and all, this is how I would've slice it. Because you don't need to resize your inputs, you can take just full background images, no?

```
.clr { clear: both; }
#myform { width: 800px; }
#myform fieldset { display: block; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: medium none; }
#myform input.txt { display: block; width: 200px; border: medium none; background: transparent url('bg_input.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0; height: 30px; text-indent: 2px; }
#myform label { float: left; width: 120px; height: 30px; }
#myform textarea { display: block; border: medium none; height: 180px; background: transparent url('bg_textarea_large.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0 !important; resize: none; }
#myform .large { width: 378px; background: transparent url('bg_input_large.jpg') no-repeat scroll 0 0; }
#myform .button {  }

#myform fieldset.addfriends { width: 300px; }
#myform fieldset.personal { width: 500px; }

    <form id="myform">
        <fieldset class="addfriends">
            <p>Enter at least 3 email addresses of your friends</p>
            <input type="text" class="txt" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" class="txt" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" class="txt" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="personal">
            <label for="name">Your name:</label><input type="text" id="name" class="txt" />
            <br />
            <label for="email">Your e-mail:</label><input type="text" id="email" class="txt" />
            <br />
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label><input type="text" id="subject" class="txt large" value="You'll love it!" />
            <br />
            <label for="message">Message:</label><textarea id="message" class="large"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" />
        </fieldset>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I need to add a wrapper to each <input> on the page for IE to make some shadows, corners etc. For modern browsers I use CSS3

Comment: have you tried something like this? http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: Yes, I have use this pluin in my projects before. But there is to dificult design, so I deside to use few divs with background image

Comment: Its on my localhost, so here is screenshot http://higgs.rghost.ru/39465098/image.png

Comment: If you have full control over the html and css I suggest you use fieldset, label and input: http://www.pixy.cz/blogg/clanky/css-fieldsetandlabels.html

Comment: I use input only. Here is my html for modern browsers
<ul id="emails">
    <li><input type="text" class="ui-text email" name="emails[]"><a href="http://localhost/tell2/nojs.php" class="removeEmailField tahoma" title="Remove field">[x]</a></li>
</ul>

and for IE http://rghost.ru/39465346.view
​

Comment: Here, I have uploaded script in intrenet, perhaps it will be easier to understand:
http://bit-labs.net/demo/tafta/?lid=1

Comment: Ok nice, now I don't see the problem since it looks almost the same in IE7 on my end

Comment: oh crap. The solution is to add position:relative to the UL tag. Now it works normally in IE7. Thanks you for trying to help!

Comment: I thought to use fixed size for inputs and use simple background image for them, but there also is textarea that should be resizeble and it has the same design. So then I desided to make one image with sprites for all fields. And I got something like flexible UI:). So now I can use it for all of my next projects.

Comment: And about your html. I did not thought to use fieldsets... Anyway I think both ways are correct. But thanks for the tip. Maybe next time I will not forget to use them)